# RecyclerView lags while loading images

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Recycler view lags too much when i'm trying to load images using glide.

How to fix it?

Comment: can you upload your code? or what you use image library? or did you have pagination?

Comment: im using glide library

Comment: bro i already mentioned what library i'm using

Comment: Actually, when i load 15 images in 15 imageview that used recyclerview, app lags too much. I'm using url of image to load images using glide in recyclclerview

Comment: hope you understand

Comment: oh sorry. then how much size of image when you load at once?

Comment: each image is about 500kb - 900kb

Comment: I think your images are so big. So you should be resize your images or add pagination in your recyclerView. it might be occurs OOM problem. And except images, loading is fast? without lags?

Comment: Well, OOM isn't (usually) going to cause lag.  Decoding 15 large images at once might, though.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use Picasso. I think you can solve your problem with this.**
Add the Picasso library in Dependency

```
dependencies {
       ...
       implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
       ...
    }
```

Sync The Project Create one imageview in Layout

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
</ImageView>
```

Add the Internet permission in Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

//Initialize ImageView

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

//Loading image from below url into imageView

```
Picasso.get().load(imageURL).resize(50, 50).centerCrop().into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

After posting my question, i searched a lot but i unable to fix lags in recyclerview while loading images from url using glide. I tried a lot of methods but nothings worked. After some days, i fix it own. Here is only quick fix method you can follow to solve it.

**Only one way to solve it [In my case]**

Only one mistake, you are making is setting large images to imageview. 
You have to make sure you are using small size of images and also small dimensions of images you are using. And also loading large data in recyclerview can cause lag in ui. To fix lags while loading large data you should use pagination in recyclerview. It will fix it.

Comment: enable cache while using glide.